# how to get custom product attribute in block file?

Tags: attributes, magento2.4.3

I have created one custom attribute on the admin product details page,
the attribute name is **hsn_code**.
now I want to get this attribute value in

> **Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Igst.php**

I need in **Igst.php** file,

here is the code that I have tried but it's not working.

**Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Igst.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ncode\GSTtax\Block\Adminhtml\Sales;
class Igst extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    //protected $collection
    /**
     * @var \Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_dataHelper;
   
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
     */
    protected $_currency;
    protected $_order; 
    //protected $_source;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->_currency = $currency;        
    }

     /**
     * Retrieve current order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getOrder();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getSource();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrencySymbol()
    {
        return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        //$productCollection->setPageSize(3); 
        return $productCollection;
       
        /*foreach ($productCollection as $product){
             echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName();            
        } */
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function initTotals() 
    {           
        $this->getParentBlock();
        $this->getOrder();
        $this->getSource();
        $this->getProductCollection();

        if(!$this->getSource()->getFee()) {
                return $this;
        }

        $productCollection = $this->getProductCollection();
        foreach ($productCollection as $productHsn) {
            //print_r($product->getHsnCode());            
            echo $productHsn->getHsnCode();
        }

        $state   = $this->getOrder()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion();
        $productionState = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('GSTtax/GSTtax/gstregion', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        if(!($state == $productionState && $productHsn)){
            $total = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'igst',
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getFee(),                                       
                    'label' => "IGST",
                ]
            );
            $this->getParentBlock()->addTotalBefore($total, 'grand_total');        
            return $this;
        }            
    } 
}
```

> Error: Call to undefined method
> Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor::getName()
> in
> /var/www/html/m243new/app/code/Test/Extension/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Igst.php:98
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/m243new/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php(64):
> Ncode\GSTtax\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Igst->initTotals()
> #1 /var/www/html/m243new/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1113):
> Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals->_beforeToHtml()
> #2 /var/www/html/m243new/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1118):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{closure}()

Comment: try using below code:
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        return $collection;

Comment: i have try this code, but when i fetch value its give me error , $collection = $this->getProductCollection()->getName();

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor::getName()

Comment: $productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName();
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
echo $_attributeValue = $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct());
```